# Postgres creating a JSON object for each query

Tags: json, postgresql

Forgive me if I'm approaching / explaining this in the wrong manner.

I have a table which is filled with information about articles we post on our site.

What I would like to do is create a JSON object which categorises by the 'sub_speciality_id' and shows the 3 most recent articles for each.

so essentially it looks like this

for each article we have an id, news_type_id, title and sub_speciality_id

So essentially I want to SELECT the different sub_speciality_ids which I can do with

```
/* selecting the sub_speciality ids where an article exists */
select DISTINCT(sub_speciality_id) from news_item where news_type_id = 1 AND sub_speciality_id is not null
```

Then for each of the sub_specialities I want to use that to produce a JSON object much like

```
SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(r))
FROM
(select * from news_item where news_type_id = 1 AND sub_speciality_id =replace_me ORDER BY create_dt DESC LIMIT 3)r
```

BUT replacing `'replace_me'` with the ID above for each

So I guess it would look something like (although I'm sure I've made some errors in formatting that):

```
{

    "sub_specialities": {
        "1": [
                    {
                    "id": 2328,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "This is a title",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 1
                    },{
                    "id": 2287,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "Blood Conservation Techniques",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 1
                    },{
                    "id": 2278,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "A Great Way to Do Apneic Oxygenation - Buccal O2",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 1
                    }],
        "2": [
                    {
                    "id": 2328,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "This is a title",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 2
                    },{
                    "id": 2287,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "Blood Conservation Techniques",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 2
                    },{
                    "id": 2278,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "A Great Way to Do Apneic Oxygenation - Buccal O2",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 2
                    }],
        "3": [
                    {
                    "id": 2328,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "This is a title",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 3
                    },{
                    "id": 2287,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "Blood Conservation Techniques",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 3
                    },{
                    "id": 2278,
                    "news_type_id": 1,
                    "title": "A Great Way to Do Apneic Oxygenation - Buccal O2",
                    "sub_speciality_id": 3
                    }]

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE t (sub_speciality_id INTEGER, news_type_id INTEGER, title TEXT, content TEXT);

INSERT INTO t
VALUES
  (1, 1, 'a', 'some text a'),
  (1, 2, 'b', 'some text b'),
  (2, 1, 'c', 'some text c'),
  (1, 1, 'd', 'some text d'),
  (2, 2, 'e', 'some text e'),
  (2, 1, 'f', 'some text f');
```

Query:

```
SELECT JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('sub_specialities', JSON_OBJECT_AGG(sub_speciality_id, item))
FROM (
  SELECT sub_speciality_id, JSON_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(t)) AS item
  FROM t
  WHERE news_type_id = 1
  GROUP BY sub_speciality_id
) AS j
```

Returns (after prettifying it):

```
{
    "sub_specialities": {
        "1": [{
            "sub_speciality_id": 1,
            "news_type_id": 1,
            "title": "a",
            "content": "some text a"
        }, {
            "sub_speciality_id": 1,
            "news_type_id": 1,
            "title": "d",
            "content": "some text d"
        }],
        "2": [{
            "sub_speciality_id": 2,
            "news_type_id": 1,
            "title": "c",
            "content": "some text c"
        }, {
            "sub_speciality_id": 2,
            "news_type_id": 1,
            "title": "f",
            "content": "some text f"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing 't' with 'news_item' but I get `ERROR:  column "t" does not exist
LINE 3:   SELECT sub_speciality_id, JSON_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(t)) AS item`

If I replace the other 't' as well I get `ERROR:  field name must not be null
SQL state: 22023`

Comment: @Charlie You probably have some records where `sub_speciality_id` is NULL. So you need to decide how to handle that, because you are using that value as a field name. If you want to exclude them, change the WHERE to `WHERE news_type_id = 1 AND sub_speciality_id IS NOT NULL`, otherwise COALESCE it, e.g. `SELECT COALESCE(sub_speciality_id, 0) AS sub_speciality_id, JSON_AGG(...) ... GROUP BY COALESCE(sub_speciality_id, 0)`

Comment: amazing thank you. One other question - how do I order by and limit so for each sub_speciality there is only 3 results?

Comment: @Charlie It needs a couple more subqueries to do that; first to get a row number per sub_speciality_id, in order to get only 3 items per sub_speciality_id; then another subquery to get a row without the row_number, because otherwise that value will be in the json object. Anyway you can take a look at it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pgqTkqHBGFfgNLFAdLDGqr/0 I've done the ordering for the LIMIT by title (in the ROW_NUMBER bit), but of course you would put whatever field you want to order by when deciding which 3 to get.